# How to obtain the vapor density at low pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, evaporation

By lookup of the CRC Handbook, I could obtain the vapor pressure of water or mercury as a function of temperature. For example, it is $138~\mathrm{Pa}$ at $400~\mathrm K$ for mercury.

Now I want to use the vapor pressure to calculate the vapor density with the equation of state of ideal gas $p=\rho R_\text{spe} T=\rho \frac{R_\text{g}}{M} T$, where $p$ takes the value of vapor pressure, $T$ is the corresponding temperature at saturation in $K$, the specific gas constant $R_\text{spe}$ of vapor is given by the universal gas constant $R_\text{g}$ divided by the molar mass $M$ with $R_\text{g}=8.3145~\mathrm{J/(mol\cdot K)}$ and $M=200.59~\mathrm{g/mol}$ for mercury for example. Then the vapor density $\rho$ at saturation could be calculated readily.

**My question is whether or not I can still use the *classical ideal gas law* at such a low pressure, for example $\sim100$ Pa for mercury or $10$ -$100~\mathrm{ Pa}$ for water vapor?**

Comment: The ideal gas approximation actually works even better at low pressure.

Comment: For water, besides the look-up tables, there are functions of temperature that are useful across a very broad range of temperatures.

Comment: @JonCuster, you meant the vapor density as a function of equilibrium temperature? And where is it? Thanks.

Comment: Google is your friend. I found several references searching on 'saturated water vapor pressure calculation' - the Engineering Toolbox gives expressions for both the vapor pressure and density of water.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the following picture [[source](http://2012books.lardbucket.org/books/principles-of-general-chemistry-v1.0/s14-08-the-behavior-of-real-gases.html)], the ideal gas approximation actually becomes *better* at low pressure:

[image]

You can also see from the picture that the validity of the approximation also depends on the gas you are considering. If you want a better approximation, I would suggest you use the [van der Waals equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation). You can find the values of the constants to plug into the formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_constants_(data_page)).